# GET THE NUMBER OF FILES WITH A SPECIFIC EXTENSION IN A SPECIFIC FOLDER (BATCH)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables, listings

I've searched and tryed everything to get the number of file with a specific extension but i did found nothing, so i would need some help please, my problem :

**I've got multiple files with differents extensions, and i need to put the number of files that has for extension .NDS in a variable**

Ex: (for the exemple, i gonna put 2 files that has the extension .nds)

```
@echo off
set number=0
FOR %%f in (%CD%\files\*.nds) DO set /a number=%number%+1
echo Nintendo DS : %number% game(s)
pause
```

Output:

```
Nintendo DS : 1
```

but whyyyy, i said that every .nds files that are in %CD%\files found, you set +1 to %number%, and there are 2 files: so why is he giving me 1 and not 2 ?
Do someone can give me a solution

Comment: Does the value of `%CD%` contain a space? If so, you'll either need quotes around the path or simply remove the `%CD%\ ` part.

Comment: As you've already defined a variable named `number` with a string value of `0`, `set /a number=%number%+1` will always be `0+1`, which will always result in `1`. What you need to do is to read the usage information for the `set` command, then change your command to match, i.e. `set /a number += 1`, or even `set /a number=number+1`. This question is clearly solved by reading the command help, which you should have done before posting here. Please, in future, try not to post such questions again, they are of no help to furure readers, as they, themselves, should have read the help pages too!

Comment: The title appears to be comprised entirely of SHOUTING. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially falling into the delayed expansion trap. But the `SET /A` command gives you some options to not have to use delayed expansion with the variable.

Change the set command to one of these option.

```
set /a "number=number + 1"
```

or

```
set /a "number+=1"
```

This explained in the HELP file for the `SET` command.

**Any non-numeric strings in the
expression are treated as environment variable names whose values are
converted to numbers before using them.  If an environment variable name
is specified but is not defined in the current environment, then a value
of zero is used.  This allows you to do arithmetic with environment
variable values without having to type all those % signs to get their
values.**